# PostgreSQL: The database cluster initialization failed

Tags: postgresql, windows

Both `C:\PostgreSQL` and `C:\PostgreSQL\data` have `postgres` user with full access and admin rights.

I ran postgresql-9.1.2-1-windows.exe from postgres user as admin. Target `C:\PostgreSQL`

Every way I try, I get "The database cluster initialization failed."

Questions

- Is it OK to run everything w/o being a Windows Service?
- Is there a work-around to install as Windows Service?

I am trying to setup PostGIS to work with GeoDjango.

I was able to manually install PostGIS. New to PostgreSQL and I am having a crisis of confidence over all of this. Coming from MySQL to PostgreSQL for the first time.

---

Pertinent log output from C:\Users\Larry\AppData\Local\Temp\install-postgresql.log:

```
WScript.Network initialized...
Called IsVistaOrNewer()...
    'winmgmts' object initialized...
    Version:6.1
    MajorVersion:6
Ensuring we can read the path C: (using icacls) to Larry:
    Executing batch file 'radA3CF7.bat'...
    Output file does not exists...
Called IsVistaOrNewer()...
    'winmgmts' object initialized...
    Version:6.1
    MajorVersion:6
Ensuring we can read the path C:\PostgreSQL (using icacls) to Larry:
    Executing batch file 'radA3CF7.bat'...
    Output file does not exists...
Called IsVistaOrNewer()...
    'winmgmts' object initialized...
    Version:6.1
    MajorVersion:6
Ensuring we can read the path C:\PostgreSQL\data (using icacls) to Larry:
    Executing batch file 'radA3CF7.bat'...
    Output file does not exists...
Called IsVistaOrNewer()...
    'winmgmts' object initialized...
    Version:6.1
    MajorVersion:6
Ensuring we can write to the data directory (using icacls) to  Larry:
    Executing batch file 'radA3CF7.bat'...
    Output file does not exists...
Failed to ensure the data directory is accessible (C:\PostgreSQL\data)
    Executing batch file 'radA3CF7.bat'...
    Output file does not exists...
Called Die(Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb)...
Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb
```

Suggestions?

Comment: see install log (it should be somewhere on disk, probably in %TEMP%)

Comment: Please see pertinent log output.

Comment: Does the postgres *Windows* user have **full** read and write privileges on C:\PostgreSQL\data?

Comment: Yes, AND per a suggestion elsewhere, I gave Users Modify permissions to that directory.

Comment: @LarryEitel: but "*Failed to ensure the data directory is accessible (C:\PostgreSQL\data)*" seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: Indeed. However, I have verified that postgres has Full permissions in PostgreSQL & PostgreSQL/data. I also uninstalled while leaving these DIRs and permissions. Reinstalled FROM user postgres. Same outcome. :( I am thinking to try version 8X. I just need a stable stack for running GeoDjango.

Comment: I typically just download the binary and run initdb with a privileged account

Comment: IIRC, permissions (and how they work) on the base of the C: drive are slightly different from the permissions given for directories (and elsewhere) in Windows; check the properties for your C: drive and look at how the permissions are set up. You may wish to create the PostgreSQL directory as a sub-directory, using an existing directory that the account already has permissions for.

Comment: Install log is in Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\install-postgresql.txt. Note that AppData is hidden, but you can just type it into the path textbox at the top of Explorer.

Comment: I had similar trouble installing on a 2012R2 VM. Company policy was to install apps on D:, leaving C: for OS. D: was on a SAN somewhere. Some kind of access control issue seemed to prevent the init process working. I solved it by installing in C:\Postgres. (Note that C:\Program Files\ also has more stringent access controls, and others have reported problems installing it in there.)

Comment: Had this problem on Windows 10. For me the solution was to choose a locale different from [Default Locale] when prompted during install.

Comment: I can't answer this question, but I solved this by following [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/248584/205787)

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue installing 9.1.4 on Windows 7. I managed to find a [solution online that worked](http://forums.holdemmanager.com/general-support/150771-solved-postgresql-database-cluster-initialisation-failed.html).

The steps I followed are:

1. Uninstall PostgreSQL
2. Delete the postgres user if it still exists.

   ```
   net user postgres /delete
   ```
3. Create the postgres user with a password you can remember

   ```
   net user /add postgres <password>
   ```
4. Add the postgres user to the Administrators group

   ```
   net localgroup administrators postgres /add
   ```
5. Add the postgres user to the Power Users group

   ```
   net localgroup "power users" postgres /add
   ```
6. Run a command window as the postgres user

   ```
   runas /user:postgres cmd.exe
   ```
7. Run the install file from within the command window.

   ```
   C:\Download\postgresql-9.1.4-1-windows.exe
   ```

   This should run the installation successfully.
8. Remove the postgres user from the Administrators group.

   ```
   net localgroup administrators postgres /delete
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Unfortunately, I have since shifted this project to Mongodb. I am not in a position at the moment to confirm your suggestion.

Comment: I want to confirm that the solution worked for me. Setup:
Postgres 9.1 64 bit and PostGIS 2.0.1 x64

Comment: This is a well-known issue with re-installation of PostgreSQL that is running as a service, and I have personally run into the situation that this answer addresses.  The installer leaves behind an account upon removal or upgrade, but the 2nd installation does not factor this in; the resulting credential disparity between installations creates havoc.  The most-common answer is the one Imraan gives; un-install, remove the offending account, then re-install.

Comment: @AveryPayne: alternatively: remember the correct password for the postgres service account. I have installed Postgres a lot on systems where it was already installed and never had a problem with an existing service account. The wording in the installer could have been improved though (with 9.2 Postgres doesn't use an explicit account any longer btw)

Comment: Keep in mind that, for step 4, `administrators` is locale dependent. For example, in PT-BR it is `administradores`. And, in step 5, `"power users"` is `"usuários avançados"`.

Comment: And this procedure didn't fix it for me. I'm still getting the cluster initialization failed message during installation.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error message when trying to install 9.2.4.  My issue was because even though the Win2k8 server had %SYSTEMROOT%\system32 as part of the path, no programs could "see" anything in C:\Windows\system32.  The installer heavily uses icacls.exe during the init routine.  Since my path was screwed up, the installer bombed out.

Once I explicitly added C:\Windows\system32 to the SYSTEM's Path environment variable and re-ran the installer as an admin, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (as I saw from the postgresql.log file in %temp% folder of Windows), it was because the installer was unable to find doskey.exe even though the path to c:\windows\system32 folder was given in the environment variable path of windows.
So I opened up a command prompt, typed `set PATH=%PATH%;c:\windows\system32` and ran the installer from the command prompt itself. It worked! :)

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me. I had no use postgres.

So I deleted/uninstalled everything.  Ran cmd as administrator.

Then ran the installer from command line (as admin) and selected a completely new location for the data directory.

I have now succesfully reinstalled postgres, after half a day of jiggery pokery.

Comment: i did that and still didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has to do with write permission on folder. 
Create the folder / data into PostgreSQL \ 9.2 for example, and give full permission to the user. 
Try reinstalling again.