# Postgresql 12.2 "Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly. The database cluster initialisation failed" on windows 10

Tags: postgresql, installation, windows, postgresql-12

I get this error whenever I try to install Postgresql 12.2

> "Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete
>   correctly. The database cluster initialisation failed".

I followed this post
[Pg install: "The database cluster initialisation failed"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28836/pg-install-the-database-cluster-initialisation-failed/28893)

My comspec is fine and my region setting is fine. So I don't know what else to do. I'm running on Windows 10 and I had postgresql 11 on my laptop before but uninstalled it. I also tried installed with admin privileges on.

Comment: You can try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61115811