# Postgresql 11.5 installation problem

Tags: postgresql, installation

While installing PostgreSQL I keep getting the message:

> "Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete
>   correctly  The database cluster initialisation failed."

This seems to prevent me from using PGadmin correctly.

In the install log I have found the following section which seems to indicate where things went wrong.

I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem.

```
Executing batch file 'rad7C33E.bat'...
    The program "postgres" was found by "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/bin/initdb.exe"
but was not the same version as initdb.
Check your installation.

Called Die(Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb)...
Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb

Script stderr:
 Program ended with an error exit code

Error running cscript //NoLogo "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11/installer/server/initcluster.vbs" "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" "postgres" "****" "C:\Users\JesseDanckaarts\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_6f373c7c91" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\data" 5432 "Dutch,Netherlands" 0: Program ended with an error exit code
Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly
 The database cluster initialisation failed.
Executing icacls "C:\Users\JesseDanckaarts\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_cb3c83cf49" /inheritance:r
Script exit code: 0
```

I have tried the following without luck so far:

- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Running_%26_Installing_PostgreSQL_On_Native_Windows#Common_installation_errors
- https://webkul.com/blog/postgresql-windows-installation-problem-running-post-install-step-installation-may-not-complete-correctly/
- https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-cluster-initialisation-failures-no-error-windows/

and many more!

If anyone knows what could be the problem I'd be very grateful!

Comment: Looks like there is another `postgres` executable on the `PATH`. Deinstall all other PostgreSQL installations and make sure there is no other `postgres` executable around.

Comment: You don't need to install Postgres in order to use pgAdmin. If you just want to connect to an existing server with pgAdmin, it's enough to download and install **that**: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have already tried uninstalling and even manually removing all leftovers.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I will be running a local database to use with Mendix.

Comment: You wrote "*prevent me from using PGadmin*" so I assumed you just want to use pgAdmin

Answer (score 6):

Cross posting from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57897738/88411):

I've just struggled with this for several hours, so I'm posting this for anyone else who winds up here.

Initially, all I could find were two bug reports on the `pgsql-bugs` mailing list:

[BUG #15856: The program "postgres" was found by "initdb" but was not the same version as initdb.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/15856-97c7d2fd3b86f13d@postgresql.org)

[BUG #15970: Db initialization error - initdb.exe and postgres not same version](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/15970-8658025150401043@postgresql.org)

The specific symptoms are:

```
The program "postgres" was found by ".../initdb.exe" but was not the same version as initdb.
```

and although the versions match, you get this:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin>postgres -V
WARNING:  01000: could not determine encoding for locale
"<some encoding>.utf8": codeset is "CPutf8"
```

If these are your symptoms, the issue is that you have your region/language settings set to use UTF-8 (beta setting).  This causes problems with lots of programs, and PostgreSQL is one of them.  Disable this and re-install and you should be fine.

[image: UTF8 Region Settings screenshot]

Comment: This is *godlike* answer! You just stopped my 2 hours of setup mayhem. Guess what... even in postgres 12, this can still be reproduced. Did you file this into enterprisedb?

Comment: Still the same in 12.2.2. Been trying to get it installed for hours, and if I hadn't found this answer...

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! This workaround worked flawlessly when upgrading from 12 to 13. I would never have thought about it.